# text on Doughnut react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text, react-chartjs-2

how i can write on a Doughnut in react-chartjs-2,, all the answers show how to write in the middle of a Doughnut and not on the Doughnut,attaching a picture:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Please review the document I mentioned below. This datalabels plugin will help you labeling chartjs chart. I linked Doughnut chart page.
https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/doughnut.html